# Spark Java scala error

Tags: java, scala, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

Hey I want to use spark in my Java Project :

I already add this dependency to my pom file :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried this code :

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class sparkSQL {
    public void query() {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();
    }
}
```

I called this function in my main but I got this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Cloneable
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:111)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:56)
>       at realtimequeries.sparkSQL.query(sparkSQL.java:7)
>       at main.main(main.java:25)
>   Blockquote
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Cloneable
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 16 more
>
> Blockquote

I don't understand why I got this error, because normally JavaSparkContext has been created for this utilisation :

> A Java-friendly version of SparkContext that returns JavaRDDs and works with Java collections instead of Scala ones.

I already take a look at the pom of the spark-core_2.11 dependency I had and it's seems that we can find a scala dependency :

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-hive_2.10/1.4.0/spark-hive_2.10-1.4.0.pom

Did I miss something ? What I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same problem, could you provide some info, on how you managed to overcome it?
I'm new to the Spark-Java concept, so I would like to know, where are the pom files etc, in full detail :/

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore so I can't help you since I choose another way but you can look the answer of @Atul Soman.

Answer (score 4):

The class scala.Cloneable is present in scala-library*.jar. This error is gone for me after adding scala-library to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix scala versions like 2.11 and 2.12 for different dependencies (make sure you are using the same scala version for all libraries).

For e.g. spark-core_2.11 is build using 2.11 scala version. So the below would not work:

// would not work
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.4'
    compile group: 'io.delta', name: 'delta-core_2.12', version: '0.4.0'

// this would work; note the change: 2.11 -> 2.12
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '2.4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version: '2.4.4'
    compile group: 'io.delta', name: 'delta-core_2.12', version: '0.4.0'

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JavaSparkContext` to work with Spark from Java, but you still need scala since Spark is written in scala. Most of the operations are internally transformed to scala, or work internally with scala classes. You can program everything in Java but you will still need scala in your classpath.

So, in order to fix your error, you need to install scala and make `SCALA_HOME` point to the directory you installed it.

Comment: @Spierki one thing is resolving dependencies, and a very different one installing a programming language. You need to install it manually unfortunately

Comment: I already install it and add the line export SCALA_HOME=/usr/bin/scala in my bashrc file, but still getting the error. Anything to do in eclipse to make the project find it?

Comment: @Spierki adding it to the bashrc I think it won't do the actual export until you log in again. Anyway, can you `ls` your `/usr/bin/scala` and post what it gives you?

Comment: It's seems that scala isn't a folder, it's an executable. It launch the scala prompt in the terminal. I add this path because it's what give my the command : which scala

Comment: @Spierki yeah that is why I asked. You set SCALA_HOME to the executable that points to the instalation folder. You need to set SCALA_HOME to the instalation folder too. If you don't know where it is, open the executable with `vi` or something and ser where it points too.

Comment: In this file I can see : # Finding the root folder for this Scala distribution
SCALA_HOME="/usr/share/java" and # Constructing the extension classpath
TOOL_CLASSPATH="$SCALA_HOME/scala-compiler.jar:$SCALA_HOME/scala-library.jar:$SCALA_HOME/scalap.jar:$SCALA_HOME/scala/jline.jar:$SCALA_HOME/jansi.jar"  I tried to add this two lines in my bashrc, restart eclipse but still not working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81653/discussion-between-spierki-and-balduz).